# Asymptotic elementary expression for the antiderivative of $x^x$

Tags: integration, asymptotics, elementary-functions, differential-algebra

It is well known that there exists no elementary function $f$ with

$$\int x^x\,dx \quad = \quad f$$

Is there an elementary function $g$ such that

$$\int x^x\,dx \quad \tilde{} \quad g$$

in the sense that the quotient of both sides converges to $1$ as the argument goes to infinity? Results like [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)) do not apply to such expressions as there is no rigid algebraic structure to work with.

*(For the purposes of this question, [Wikipedia's definition of "elementary function"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) is used.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer can be found in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function

A special function, called "Sophomore's dream" function is defined as :
$$\text{Sphd}(\alpha,x)=\int_0^x t^{\alpha t}dt$$
From the properties of this function, an asymptotic expansion is derived Eq.(6:4). The first term, Eq.(9.2) is :
$$\text{Sphd}(\alpha,x)\sim \frac{x^{\alpha x}}{\alpha\big(1+\ln(x)\big)}$$
So, for $x$ large $$\int x^x dx \sim \frac{x^x}{1+\ln(x)}$$

Comment: This is awesome! (I noticed that you are the author of that paper – how fortunate that you happened to log in just today.)

Comment: The follow-up question would now be whether every elementary function has an *asymptotically* elementary antiderivative. For exponentials, this now appears very plausible. What about, say, $\sin(x)/x$?

Comment: Of course , special functions for the antiderivatives of all elementary functions have not been defined and standardized. $\text{Si}(x)$ is the antiderivative of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html . A paper for general public about special functions  is available on Scribd : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales

Comment: What I meant is, does the antiderivative of $\sin(x)/x$ have an elementary asymptotic expression like $x^x/(1+\ln(x))$ is for $\int x^x\,dx$?

Comment: The asymptotic expression of Ei(x)=antiderivative of sin(x)/x is common in the handbooks of special functions. On line : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Si%28x%29 See the formula "series expansion at $x=\infty$ ".