# Why does the integral of $x^x$ not have a non-elementary solution.

Tags: calculus, integration

If a function like $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ can have a solution to its integral in the form of a non-elementary function $Si(x)=\int_0^x{\frac{\sin t}{t}}dt$ , then why can't the function $x^x$ have a non-elementary solution to its integral in the form of $\int_0^x{t^t}dt$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It *does* have a non-elementary solution.  Whether or not this has been *named* is a different question.  If it doesn't have a name, it's probably because it hasn't been useful to a lot of people.

Comment: @johnnyb Thanks for the answer and clarifying that for me. It seems that the integral probably hasn't been named as i couldn't find anything online that references that integrals non-elementary solution.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1068896/42969

Comment: Maybe the question should be: Some non-elementary functions have standard names, like Si.  But why does $\int_0^x{t^t}dt$ not have a standard name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does have one, see [Sophomores dream function](https://tetrationforum.org/attachment.php?aid=788). The notation isn't as commonly used as $Si(x)$ but you'll see the following notation:

$$Sphd(\alpha ; x) = \int_{0}^{x} {t^{\alpha t}dt}$$

So you'd write the integral of $t^t$ as

$$Sphd(1 ; x) = \int_{0}^{x} {t^{t}dt}$$

or sometimes simply

$$Sphd(x) = \int_{0}^{x} {t^tdt}$$